# solusOs - is based on what linux distro?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, solus

is the solus Os based on ubuntu or debian? is it good to replace it with linux mint cinnamon?

my linux mint is a little bit slow. I want something to have both beutiful environment and based in ubuntu. I am a php web developer.

fast booting is another great preference.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is built from the scratch, used to be based on Debian.

[Solus on distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=Solus)

Comment: so cant install ubuntu or debian packages on it?

Comment: No, you have to install software from their repositories using their package manager.